# connection closed before handshake error in node

Tags: socket.io

Thanks you a millions guys.

im having an new error on client side. below is my code for server side. when I run this code. I can see an error in my browser. whic is : Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

I have no idea how to solve it. I am very new to this kinda things. I am sorry but cud advise anything for this ?? Thanks a millions :)

```js
 var express = require('express');
var app= express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8888, function(){ console.log("running bro");});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('turnon', function (data) {
        console.log(data.turnon);

        //serialPort.write("on");

    });

    socket.on('turnoff', function(data){
        console.log(data.turnoff);
        // serialPort.write("off");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Web to serial Arduino">
  <title>Web to serial Arduino</title>

  <script src="socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script>
    //var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
      'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner top">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="Drawing.png" alt="logo" class="sitelogo">
    </a>
    <div class="w3-right toptext w3-wide">An Arduino project for robotic Arm</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen background" style="background-image:url('http://cdns.nocamels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/bigstock-Business-technologies-today-43292197.jpg');" data-img-width="1600" data-img-height="1064">
    <div class="content-a">
      <div class="content-b">
        <br>WELCOME TO Arduino "A simple function to test node.js"
        <br>
        <div class="button" onclick="socket.emit('turnon', { turnon:'on'});">
          Turn On
        </div> <span style="color: #ffffff;"><a class="button primary-button" onclick="socket.emit('turnoff', {turnoff:'off'});">Turn off</a>&nbsp;</span>
        <br>
        <div class="button" onclick="console.log('connected');">
          connect
        </div> <span style="color: #ffffff;"><a class="button primary-button" onclick="console.log('reset');">Reset</a>&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just figure out that in my html file if  change this : var socket = io('http://localhost:8888', {'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});          to this : var socket = io('http://localhost:8888',); ... it gives an different error. it give and not found 404 error. I guess its client side but I cant figure out

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different ports in the server (8888) and in the client (8080), you should use the same one.

Comment: I did that and pointed out this in my comment as well. However problm still persist :(